# Generating Box2D body(collision map) from tilemap efficiently

Tags: java, box2d, libgdx, tiles, game-physics

I am working on a platformer game that will use tile maps, which I don't know if is a good idea!

I've made a neat tile map editor with tools for setting a spawn point etc. but now that I want to be able to test play the game after editing map and for future use I need of course integrate physics which I've done with Box2D which comes with LibGDX!

I am creating a method to create a collision map from tile map which has data if tile is collideable or not!

So I came up with this great idea:

loop through the map and if we find a colliding tile loop through its neighbor tiles and see if they're colliding too, and do this til noncolliding tile is found when we set width and height for the colliding rectangle

after we got bunch of rectangle I sort them in order from biggest square to smallest so we get biggest pieces and I add the rectangles to final list and check against the final rect if any of them overlaps with current body so I don't have overlapping bodys

But you know, code tells more than 1000 words, right?

```
    public void createBody() {
    List<Rectangle> allRects = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
    for(int x = 0; x < info.getWidth(); x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < info.getHeight(); y++) {
            if(tiles[x][y].getInfo().isColliding()) {
                int width = 1;
                int height = 1;

                //loop through neighbors horizontally
                for(int i = 0; i < info.getWidth() - x; i++) {
                    if(!tiles[x + i][y].getInfo().isColliding()) {
                        //if tile is not clipped, we set width to i which is current x offset


                        width = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }


                //only if width is bigger than zero can the rect have any tiels..
                if(width > 0) {
                    boolean breakingBad = false;
                    //loop through neighbors horizontally
                    for(int j = 0; j < info.getHeight() - y; j++) {
                        //loop though neigbors vertizally
                        for(int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
                            //check if tile is not colliding 
                            if(!tiles[x + i][y + j].getInfo().isColliding()) {
                                //and if so, we set height to j which is current y offset
                                height = j;

                                //breaking bad aka leaving both loops
                                breakingBad = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if(breakingBad) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(width * height > 0)
                    allRects.add(new Rectangle(x, y, width, height));
            }
        }
    }

    Collections.sort(allRects, new Comparator<Rectangle>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Rectangle o1, Rectangle o2) {
            Integer o1Square = o1.width * o1.height;
            Integer o2Square = o2.width * o2.height;
            return o2Square.compareTo(o1Square);
        }
    });

    List<Rectangle> finalRects = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
    mainloop:
    for(Rectangle rect: allRects) {
        for(Rectangle finalRect: finalRects) {
            if(finalRect.contains(rect)) {
                continue mainloop;
            }
        }
        finalRects.add(rect);
    }

    for(Rectangle rect: finalRects) {
        PolygonShape polyShape = new PolygonShape();
        polyShape.setAsBox((float)rect.getWidth() / 2, (float)rect.getHeight() / 2, Vector2.tmp.set((float)rect.getCenterX(), (float)rect.getCenterY()), 0f);

        mapBody.createFixture(polyShape, 1);
        polyShape.dispose();
    }

}
```

[image: inefficient?]

however this sill seems pretty inefficient because for some reasons its still creating smaller fixtures than it could be possible, for example in upper right corner

also its creating single fixtures in the corners of the center rectangle and I can't figure out why!

Is the whole idea all inefficient, and should I use other method or manually create collision maps or what could be the best idea?

Originally each tile was its own fixture which caused weird bugs on their edges as expected

Comment: While we talking about inefficiency, in the 'compareTo' method, you perform a lot of autoboxing. Is 'Rectangle.width' int or Integer ?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html - its int

Comment: I tried your compare method and it turns out to be 2x more expensive than similar compare with only ints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, a custom tile mapping tool is a great idea on the surface, but you're reinventing the wheel.

libGDX has built-in support for TMX maps.
http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/maps/tiled/TmxMapLoader.html

Instead of using your homebrew editor, you can use a full featured editor such as this Tiled - http://www.mapeditor.org/

So once you have a better system in place for your maps, I would look at this from an object oriented perspective. Since you want to use box2d physics, each **collidableTile** *HAS A* **body**. So all you need to do is assign a physics body to each collidableTile, and set the size according to your standard tile size.

Don't forget that there is a difference between the box2d world and your game screen, where box2d is measured in metric units, and your screen is measured in pixels. So you need to do some math to set positions and size properly. If you want a set of tiles to share a body, you may want to pass in the body as a parameter when you construct each collidableTile, and then adjust the size of the body based on how many adjacent tiles you can find. More complex shapes for the physics body may be more complex.

You can also save resources by setting those tiles to 'sleep', where box2d does a reduced simulation on those bodies until it detects a collision. If you're only using box2d for collision detection on terrain, you may want to consider other options, like using shape libraries to detect intersections, and then setting the box2d physics on your player characters body to stop downward acceleration while there is contact, or something.